# cabal install bnfc missing directory

Tags: haskell, cabal, bnfc

I'm new to Haskell, trying to write a program for compiler construction class.

I installed the haskell-platform package on my ubuntu 13.10, and then (without messing around with anything after installing haskell platform) tried to run the following command:

```
$ sudo cabal install bnfc
```

which results with:

```
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring BNFC-2.6.0.3...
cabal: The following installed packages are broken because other packages they
depend on are missing. These broken packages must be rebuilt before they can
be used.
package process-1.1.0.2 is broken due to missing package
directory-1.2.0.1-508733a890139bbedb8aa76468431462
Failed to install BNFC-2.6.0.3
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
BNFC-2.6.0.3 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

As I try installing package directory it says the package is already installed.
Can anyone help?

Comment: have you tried `cabal update` beforehand?

Comment: Avoid using `sudo` with `cabal`. And rebuild `process` and `directory` by just `cabal install`ing them.

Answer (score 1):

I also am using Ubuntu 13.10 with the haskell platform package, and bnfc installs for me.

There are a few things you can check....

1. Don't use sudo with cabal install (by default cabal installs packages in your own home directory, using sudo might be causing trouble by giving the wrong file ownerships, or perhaps trying to put files in /root, or even overwriting /usr stuff)
2. Rename ~/.cabal/ and ~/.ghc/, and rebuild them by running "cabal update" (You may need to re-add ~/.cabal/bin/cabal from the moved location after the move).  These hold installed packages and their info....  Since you have a new vanilla install, these should basically be empty, although the meta info in them may be corrupt. (if for some reason this makes things worse, you can always restore the original directory....  If it solves the problem, you can delete the original .cabal and .ghc)
3. You can get more info about why a package isn't installing by doing the following

   cabal unpack bnfc      #This will download and unpack the source code
   cd BNFC-2.6.0.3        #enter the newly created source directory
   cabal configure        #This checks that all system dependencies are met
   cabal build            #This builds the package
   cabal install          #This installs the package in ~/.cabal/

(You may have to iterate to another package if a dependency isn't met)

I think 2. may solve your problem, as the error message you showed implies that the build process is hooked on finding a very specific version of the directory package, rather than the latest one.  This happened to me once and cleaning out .cabal solved the problem for me.